# KnockoutJs doesn't react to custom events

Tags: javascript, jquery, data-binding, knockout.js

I'm binding my ViewModel's `isChecked` property to a `data-whatever` attribute. The value of this attribute is changed by jQuery:

```
$element.data('whatever', "true")
```

KnockoutJs doesn't notice this change and my ViewModel's property doesn't change. How can I make KnockoutJs notice it?

I tried something like that, but it didn't work:

JavaScript "view layer" script:

```
$element.data('whatever', "true")
$element.trigger("myCustomEvent")
```

The view:

```
<div data-bind="attr: { 'data-whatever': isChecked, event : {myCustomEvent: checkedFunction} }">
```

`checkedFunction` is just an empty method in the ViewModel to fit the event binding syntax. It still looks like KnockoutJs is not listening to `myCustomEvent`.

**EDIT**

As Fisherman suggested I used `$element.attr` instead of `$element.data`, but it still doesn't work:

```
<html>
<div id="test" data-bind="attr: { 'data-whatever': isChecked }">my div</div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://knockoutjs.com/downloads/knockout-3.2.0.js"></script>
<script>
var vm = {
    isChecked : ko.observable("one"),
};

$(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
    console.log($('#test').attr('data-whatever')); // "one"
    $('#test').attr('data-whatever', 'two');
    console.log($('#test').attr('data-whatever')); // "two"
    console.log(vm.isChecked()); // // "one" again, thouh it should be "two"
});

</script>
</html>
```

even if I add the event:

```
<html>
<div id="test" data-bind="attr: { 'data-whatever': isChecked, event :{ myCustomEvent : aFunction }}">my div</div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://knockoutjs.com/downloads/knockout-3.2.0.js"></script>
<script>
var vm = {
    isChecked : ko.observable("one"),
    aFunction : function(){ }
};

vm.isChecked.subscribe(function(){
    console.log("hit the event"); // never happens
});

$(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
    console.log($('#test').attr('data-whatever')); // "one"
    $('#test').attr('data-whatever', 'two');
    $('#test').trigger('myCustomEvent');
    console.log($('#test').attr('data-whatever')); // "two"
    console.log(vm.isChecked()); // "one" again, though should be "two"
});

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you edit the question and create a [repro](http://sscce.org)? This would make helping you a lot easier.

Comment: KO uses jQuery, if it is available, to bind to events. Here is a sample that you could tweak: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/Lf53moaa/

Comment: @Jeroen Added the repro. Please take a look.

Comment: @RPNiemeyer Thanks for the sample, but it's not exactly what I need. I'd rather have my view model notified about the change of the attribute bound to the property. Please take a look at the edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the `data` attribute with jQuery's `data()` functions. Have a look at the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/data/

> The data- attributes are pulled in the first time the data property is
>   accessed and then are no longer accessed or mutated (all data values
>   are then stored internally in jQuery)

http://jsfiddle.net/prpL0x3j/

```
console.log($('#test').data('whatever'));
// one
$('#test').data('whatever', 'two');
console.log($('#test').data('whatever'));
// two
```

Check out the attribute of the DOM element in the developer bar - it does not change, even though jQuery's `data` value changed.

Consider using the `attr()` function: http://api.jquery.com/attr/

```
$element.attr('data-whatever', "true")
```

Comment: Good point about jquery data method. But unfortunately it still doesn't work. Please take a look at the edit